# How to compile with both C++17 and C++20 using CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, compilation, c++20

I've used both C++20 and `boost` in my project. But some boost header files can't be compiled with C++20 as they use `is_literal_type` or something else that were removed in C++20.

So is it possible to use C++17 to compile the boost header files and use C++20 for other project files? If yes, how should I configure it in CMake?

Comment: Some compilers have switches that allow them to still expose removed standard library functionality. But that's particular to a compiler, not a build system.

Comment: You can split you project into multiple object libraries and set different compiler options for each of those parts and link those object libraries at the end into one.

Comment: You should either patch boost to properly support C++20 and continue using C++20 in your project or switch your project back to C++17, avoiding mixing libraries built using different compiler options.

Comment: You cannot specify compiler options for header files; only for source files including them. Depending on how the boost headers are used you may be able to refactor your code to exclusively use the functionality some a limited number of cpp files or even move this logic to a separate static lib that is compiled with C++ 17, but does allow including the public headers in C++20 code...